# How can I make Twitter Bootstrap Collapsable Navbar opened by default?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

If one opens [Twitter Bootstrap's GitHub page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) in a browser window that is less than 980px wide, it is collapsed.

Click the button in the upper-right and it expands to show options "Home", "Get Started", "Scaffolding" etc.

Is there a way to configure Twitter Bootstrap (or write a little custom CSS or JavaScript) to make it default to showing these options?

My concern is that some users will not know to click the button in the upper-right to see site navigation options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it by just setting the height of `.container .nav-collapse.collapse` to auto.

All that happens when you toggle the menu is the height is set to auto, and a classs of collapsed is removed from the button.

Note: I've only tested this through my console, you will probably have to play around with how you directly apply the height.

Comment: The problem with this is that the first time you click on the collapse/expand icon (which should collapse the already expanded navbar) it sets the height to auto and so nothing happens. You have to click collapse/expand twice to trigger the expected behavior. I suspect some further Javascript modification is necessary here.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by adding the class `.in` with `.container .nav-collapse.collapse`.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse"> <!-- collapsed state -->
   Some html element
  </div>
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse in"> <!-- expanded state -->
   Some html element
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer. I simply added the `.in` class and everything worked great. Thanks!